# PHP if(...) readfile; else readfile returns both

Tags: php, readfile

I'm trying to make a PHP function that reads files dependent on client ip.
So far I got:

```
function getips() {

$bannedips = array('127.0.0.1','192.168.101.222');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(strpos($ip,$bannedips)){ readfile("notallwed.html");
} else {
  readfile("good.html");
}
}
```

But somehow, even if the IP is banned, it displays the notallowed page, and the good page after(under) it. If the IP is not banned, it only displays the good page.

What am I doing wrong over here? How can I stop the script after reading the banned IP, to not display the good page, if the IP is banned.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to use `in_array` instead of `strpos`.  Also use `exit;` after reading.

Comment: `if (in_array($ip, $bannedips))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! exit; did the work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check if the visitor's ip is a banned ip

```
function getips() {
    $bannedips = array('127.0.0.1','192.168.101.222');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (in_array($ip,$bannedips)) {
        readfile("notallwed.html");
    } else {
        readfile("good.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but exit; did the work for me.